# Are all parameters passed to the mapped method available to the view of the webapp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to know what different things are available to the JSP (view) of a traditional java spring webapp .

For ex , I have this method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(@ModelAttribute Person person,Map<String, Object> map, Car c) {
person.setName("Aman");
c.setNumber("12345");
map.put("person", person);
map.put("car",c);
return "index";
}
```

Now when i access them in my JSP page with this

```
<SELECT>
<option selected="selected"></option>
<option value="${person.name}">${person.name}</option>
<option value="${car.number}">${car.number}</option>
</SELECT>
```

both person and car is available to the JSP .

but in a case like this

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
    ModelMap m = new ModelMap();
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Aman");
    map.put("person", person);
    return "index";
    }
```

In this case the person isn't available to the view .So what are the different values that are available to the view of a webapp

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did not bind `Person` to Spring model in your last code, if you want to get `Person` be available to the view. You can try following;)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index() {
    ModelAndView mav= new ModelAndView("index");
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Aman");
    mav.addObject("person", person);
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  , i guessed that but why is the class car available to the view in the first example . I didn't map it too and only passed it as a parameter

Comment: @EvanRoot because you receive the model as parameter of your method, the the same map is populated to the view